# Unable to enable PHP in OSX 10.8 mountain lion

Tags: macos, apache, php

I have enabled php according to [PHP's instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php) and uncommented,

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/httpd/libphp5.so
```

in */private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*. However the line,

```
#AddModule mod_php5.c
```

does not exist in that file, nor do any #AddModule lines.  This may be the root of my problem but regardless I restarted apache with,

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

and attempted to open ~/Site/page.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My First PHP page </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "<h1> Hello World! </h1>";?>
</body>
</html>
```

in multiple web browsers.  Safari and Chromium just gave me the raw text of the file and Opera gave me

```
Hello World ";?>
```

Do I need to configure apache to add that module and how do I do that, or is there some other problem?

PS, I couldn't even open page.php with safari when it was in my home directory and other browsers tried to download it.

Answer (score 1):

If the line doesn't exist commented-out, then just add it separately. *i.e.* put a line in  `httpd.conf` that reads `AddModule mod_php5.c`.

Comment: Attempted that, doesn't work http://pastebin.com/5F2fnxKk

Comment: Attempted that, doesn't work, I suspect `mod_php5.c` doesn't exist.  So I used `find /usr -name "mod_php5.c -print` which returned null.
`cat /var/log/apache2/error_log` for more details
[link](http://pastebin.com/5F2fnxKk)